# In delayed choice experiment, entangled photon was detected at D0. Why a single entangled photon can have interference data?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, interference, double-slit-experiment, quantum-eraser

I am new here and also in physics.

I tried to understand the experiment more. In the following youtube video. the demonstration indicated that an entangled photon arrived at $D_0$ while its partner arrived at, let's say $D_2$ or $D_3$ later on. I don't know why an already entangled single photon can leave interference data on $D_0$. Isn't A PAIR of it can be form interference wave? I think I am missing some very basic physics knowledge.

[delayed choice experiment start by 6:54](http://youtu.be/KnpCH9VRvPg?t=6m54s)

Comment: A single photon does not have any interference properties. Only the ensemble of many quanta has interference properties in the theory.

Answer (score 1):

The same way a single photon in the original double slit experiment does, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment

The wave interferes with itself. A photon is just the interactable component of the wave.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273509804_Direction-Correlated_Correlated_Photons_Cannot_Self-Interfere_A_Prediction

but i saw the link and it said "Two correlated photons, coming from the same well-deﬁned cross-sectional element of a source of correlated photons, that can be registered as coming from that same area, cannot self-interfere."
Is it violate the idea of entangled photon can self interfere?

Comment: The entangled pairs don't interfere with each other, they interfere with themselves. It's like taking the original experiment and splitting the wave into two complimentary versions.  The waves still interfere with themselves but not with each other because they now have different properties (opposite in fact) and only waves that are [coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(physics)#Quantum_coherence) interfere.

Comment: "Interference usually refers to the interaction of waves that are correlated or coherent with each other, either because they come from the same source or because they have the same or nearly the same frequency" (wikipedia) Are the entangled pairs interfering themselves different from the basic understanding of interference ?

Comment: "Two correlated photons, coming from the same well-deﬁned cross-sectional element of a source of correlated photons, that can be registered as coming from that same area, cannot self-interfere." :  
 aforementioned statement doesn't say that two coherent photons from same source can't interfere.  (Actually, they can unless they were measured) Rather it says two coherent photons from the same source can't interfere if they are registered (hence measured) as from the same location. (Because determination or measurement collapses the wave function and causes interference not to occur.)

Comment: @DukeWilliam "A photon" is the energy the quantum field deposits in the detector. That energy deposition doesn't exist before it actually happens, i.e. one should not talk about "interfering photons" in the free field. Interference is the absence of interaction in linear field theories, i.e. there is no active "interference mechanism", not even in classical physics. Linear systems are merely free of self-interaction, i.e. the physics between the source and the detector is as simple as it can be. The "collapse" language is also not helpful. It's not even well defined in physics.

Comment: @FlatterMann
What are you suggesting? is my comment misleading? I don't understand what you are trying to say. Appreciate it if you explain it because I am just not deep into physics. I just tried to express what I thought I understand about the phenomena in the question.  I just don't understand technical words like "free field". Sorry for ignorance

Comment: @DukeWilliam We have a horrible mess in our language about QM. You didn't invent it, so you are not "misleading". The language that has established itself however is misleading those who are just learning about it. We need to change the language to something that is more appropriate. These are problems of science history, science writing and science education. The mental model I like to suggest is this: "A photon is an irreversible energy exchange between the electromagnetic field and an external system (with one Planck unit of angular momentum).". It avoids all the mentioned problems.

Comment: @FlatterMann I think my statement was intended to correctly mean as you said origin detection prior to the actual failure/absence of interaction ( interference) causes the photon to actually deposit energy hence no interference. But actually, there is "no prior" since origin detection cancels out interference (again cancel out interference may not be the right word) hence false future reference. I just couldn't find the right words to provide unambiguously what I mean. Maybe I lack the depth to find and sort out the right word or it's that as you said physics being physics and not mathematics.

Comment: @DukeWilliam On a closing note... the "difficulty" with physics is that much of the phenomenology is actually based on the absence of mechanisms. Linearity is the absence of self-interaction. Lorentz symmetry is the absence of a matter background etc... but we are used to thinking in categories of "causality", i.e. that something unexpected only happens if there is something else (hidden) that must have caused it. That is not the case for many physical effects (like interference). We should probably emphasize this more in the way we are teaching physics as well.